# Why triggers this noexcept operator an "overloads have similar conversions" error for MSVC but not for Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, language-lawyer, noexcept

I have the following code

```
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const noexcept
    (noexcept(static_cast<T>(1) - 1)) // comment out this line to make it work in MSVC
    {
        return static_cast<T>(1) - 1;
    }
};
struct R {
    R(int i) {}
    operator int() const { return 0; }
    int operator-(R const& o) const { return 0; }
};

bool operator==(R const& l, int r) {
    return true;
}
bool operator==(S const& l, int r) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    return S() == 3;
}
```

which compiles fine on Clang and GCC for C++11 and above but complains about

```
'R::operator -': 2 overloads have similar conversions
note: could be 'int R::operator -(const R &) const'
note: or       'built-in C++ operator-(int, int)'
note: while trying to match the argument list '(T, int)' with [ T=R ]
```

in MSVC.

What's puzzling me is that removing the [noexcept operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) on the `template operator T()` on `struct S` makes the error disappear. Its expression is the exact same as the one in the body of the method it marks `noexcept` and I'd expect that the method body would cause the same error but it doesn't.

Why does the expression `static_cast<T>(1) - 1` result in a compiler error when compiled in an unevaluated context but not when compiled in the methods body?

Who is right here and why?

Here's a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YzzsTPb64).

Comment: Perhaps add [language-lawyer] to get a definitive answer on which compiler(s) is right